# wget article and pictures from kleinanzeigen.ebay.de returns 'ERROR 429: Too many requests'

Tags: linux, macos, posix, wget

I simply want to download an article from `kleinanzeigen.ebay.de` using **wget**, but it does not work when I also try to get pictures.
I've tried

```
 wget -k -H -p -r http://www.ebay-kleinanzeigen.de/s-anzeige/boxspringbett-polsterbett-bett-mit-tv-lift-180x200-neu-hersteller/336155125-81-1004
```

But it returns an error message:

```
  --2015-07-28 13:25:33--  http://www.ebay-kleinanzeigen.de/s-anzeige/boxspringbett-polsterbett-bett-mit-tv-lift-180x200-neu-hersteller/336155125-81-1004
  Resolving www.ebay-kleinanzeigen.de... 194.50.69.177, 91.211.75.177, 2a04:cb41:a516:1::36, ...
  Connecting to www.ebay-kleinanzeigen.de|194.50.69.177|:80... connected.
  HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
  Location: http://kleinanzeigen.ebay.de/anzeigen/s-anzeige/boxspringbett-polsterbett-bett-mit-tv-lift-180x200-neu-hersteller/336155125-81-1004 [following]
  --2015-07-28 13:25:33--  http://kleinanzeigen.ebay.de/anzeigen/s-anzeige/boxspringbett-polsterbett-bett-mit-tv-lift-180x200-neu-hersteller/336155125-81-1004
  Resolving kleinanzeigen.ebay.de... 194.50.69.177, 91.211.75.177, 2a04:cb41:f016:1::36, ...
  Reusing existing connection to www.ebay-kleinanzeigen.de:80.
  HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
  Location: http://www.ebay-kleinanzeigen.de/s-anzeige/boxspringbett-polsterbett-bett-mit-tv-lift-180x200-neu-hersteller/336155125-81-1004 [following]
  --2015-07-28 13:25:33--  http://www.ebay-kleinanzeigen.de/s-anzeige/boxspringbett-polsterbett-bett-mit-tv-lift-180x200-neu-hersteller/336155125-81-1004
  Reusing existing connection to www.ebay-kleinanzeigen.de:80.
  HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 429 Too many requests from 87.183.215.38
  2015-07-28 13:25:33 ERROR 429: Too many requests from 87.183.215.38.

  Converted 0 files in 0 seconds.
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, considering the error message you're getting...

> HTTP request sent, awaiting response... **429 Too many requests from 87.183.215.38**

...it's safe to say that - in that case - you've simply tried too often :)

But apart from that, your command should work. That it actually *doesn't work*, is due to a [bug in wget](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?37986), which seems to be unfixed up to the current version of 1.16 - I even compiled that version to verify. As the bug report suggests that it is a regression, I've also tried older versions down to 1.11.4, but without any luck.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, your script generates too many requests, therefore you've to slow it down.

One option is to wait the specified number of seconds between the retrievals by using `-w sec` or `--wait=seconds` or use the `--random-wait` parameter and see if that helps.